# RabbitMQ user with no access to management UI but can publish and subscribe

Tags: rabbitmq

We are accessing rabbitMQ using a username and password (other than admin). I was wondering if  I could create a user with no management UI access but can publish and subscribe to topics this would greatly increase the security of the application which we are building, in case the credentials are compromised nobody will be able to login through management UI.

Is there any way I can create a user with no management UI access but still will be able to publish and subscribe to topics?

```
RabbitMQ version: 3.7.10
Erlang 21.2.3
protocol: MQTT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the user without the required tags for management access. This is documented here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Answer (score 1):

As said `management` should be the right role for this case

```
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags username management
```